# Refactoring the adding process

Tags: java

```
public static void addToUserList(User newUser){

    boolean hasFound = false;

    for (User user : users) {
        if(user.getUserID() == newUser.getUserID()){
            System.out.println("DUPLICATED USER ID: " + user.getUserID() + "ALREADY EXISTS");
            hasFound = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if(hasFound = false){
        users.add(newUser);
    }


}
```

How do I refactor this code? In users arraylist, there shouldn't be duplicate users by ID.

I think using boolean variable is a bit unnecessary but I couldn't find any better solution.

P.Ss: Also if there is a convenion for these kind of coding styles, can you provide a name? Thank you.

Comment: Use a Set. In particular, use a HashSet. The coding style would be just a matter of picking a proper data structure given your problem you are trying to solve. Essentially, you don't want to add existing users to the collection, and a HashSet keeps track of only have 1 existence of a unique object.

Comment: ^ Using `HashSet` requires a proper hash... Which isn't what you normally have for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `boolean`, just `return` from the method if the user exists.

```
public static void addToUserList(User newUser){
    for (User user : users) {
        if(user.getUserID() == newUser.getUserID()){
            System.out.println("DUPLICATED USER ID: " + user.getUserID() + "ALREADY EXISTS");
            return;
        }
    }

    users.add(newUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with this.Change the == in first if to != like below and remove the last part

```
public static void addToUserList(User newUser){

    boolean hasFound = false;

    for (User user : users) {
        if(user.getUserID() != newUser.getUserID()){

            users.add(newUser);
        } 

    else{
          System.out.println("DUPLICATED USER ID: " + user.getUserID() + "ALREADY EXISTS");
       }

    }


}
```

Comment: I dont think this works, this loop adds newUser to users list several times (at every non-equal comparison).